# wxPython: wx.Panel of AuiManager has empty space of gray

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to make a window with 2 panels. One panel is just a notebook panel. The second panel contains a toolbar on top and a text control on the bottom. I want to arrange this panel in my frame using wx.aui.AuiManager.

The problem is that I get a **big empty space of grey in my custom panel**.

Here is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.aui
import images # contains toolbar icons

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                            "AUI Tutorial",
                            size=(600,400))

        self._mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager()
        self._mgr.SetManagedWindow(self)

        notebook = wx.aui.AuiNotebook(self)
        nb_panel = TabPanel(notebook)
        my_panel = MyPanel(self)
        notebook.AddPage(nb_panel, "First Tab", False)

        self._mgr.AddPane(notebook,
                          wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("notebook-content").
                          CenterPane().PaneBorder(False))
        self._mgr.AddPane(my_panel,
                          wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("txtctrl-content").
                          CenterPane().PaneBorder(False))
        self._mgr.GetPane("notebook-content").Show().Top().Layer(0).Row(0).Position(0)
        self._mgr.GetPane("txtctrl-content").Show().Bottom().Layer(1).Row(0).Position(0)

        self._mgr.Update()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """
    My panel with a toolbar and richtextctrl
    """
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent,id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self,-1)
        toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_EXIT, '', images._rt_smiley.GetBitmap())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnExit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)

        toolbar.Realize()
        sizer.Add(toolbar,proportion=0,flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_TOP)

        text = ""
        txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, text, wx.Point(0, 0), wx.Size(150, 90),
                           wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)

        sizer.Add(txtctrl,proportion=0,flag=wx.EXPAND)        
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnExit(self,event):
        self.Close()


class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent,id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**So, how do I fix my code so that I don't have that grey block taking up MyPanel? Also, my toolbar button doesn't seem to run self.OnExit(). Why is that?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the line:

```
self._mgr.GetPane("notebook-content").Show().Top().Layer(0).Row(0).Position(0)
```

As for the OnExit() handler, it is firing!
If you want to exit the application, replace it with app.Exit()

Comment: Awesome!  I read your answer 1 minute after doing this and it works! Also, app.Exit() did the trick. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept the answer if its correct. Also is your images module your own?

Comment: The images module was from the wxPython DEMO in the demo directory. I would love to vote for your answer but I don't have enough reputation points (it says I need at least 15). :(

Comment: I don't think you need to 15 to accept an answer, you just need it to upvote. So you can still accept this as the correct answer. Was also wondering about the images module, as I just don't seem to have it at all in my installation! And can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: Yes, I hit the checkmark button to accept your correct answer. That's weird about the image.py module. Private message me your email and I can email it to you.

Comment: @lacks, the images module is part of the wxPython demo's source code.  It is just image data created from a bunch of image files with the img2py tool.